# Drawing Line Effect on Touch Like Fruit Ninja or Veggie Samurai in And Engine

Tags: android, andengine

I want to draw a line in AndEngine with the effect of a blade similar to Fruit Ninja or Veggie Samurai. 
Can anyone help me? and give a sample code?

Comment: have you tried to do this? if so, are you having troubles?

Comment: Yes I tried to do this by using line drawing... but I came to know that Its not line drawing its image drawing...I have the iphone code but I dont know how to convert it into Android code.

Comment: Are you able to find solution for this problem? Then please share some knowledge with us.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, I am late but hope this will help others.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

        final float touchX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
        final float touchY = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();

        if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
            initTrail(touchX, touchY);
            swipeGestureSprite = addSwipeSprite(touchX, touchY);
        } else if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()) {

            moveTrail(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY(), 0);

            if (swipeGestureSprite != null) {
                swipeGestureSprite.setX(touchX);
                swipeGestureSprite.setY(touchY);
            }
        } else if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {

            mScene.detachChild(this.particleSystem);

            if (swipeGestureSprite != null) {
                this.mScene.detachChild(swipeGestureSprite);
                swipeGestureSprite = null;
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }




    private void initTrail(float mX, float mY) {
        this.particleEmitter = new PointParticleEmitter(mX, mY);
        this.particleSystem = new SpriteParticleSystem(particleEmitter, 1000, 1000, 5000, this.mRibbon, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new BlendFunctionParticleInitializer<Sprite>(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE));
        particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new ExpireParticleInitializer<Sprite>(1));
        particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new ScaleParticleModifier<Sprite>(0, 1, 1, 0f));
        particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new AlphaParticleModifier<Sprite>(0, 1, 1, 0));
        this.mScene.attachChild(particleSystem);
    }


private void moveTrail(float trailX, float trailY, int count) {
        if (particleEmitter == null) {
            initTrail(trailX, trailY);
        }

        particleEmitter.setCenter(trailX, trailY);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use point particle effect and use line drawing algorithm in that to create line between points. Line drawn using particle represent more reality and also the particle represent the dynamic way so you can destroy it. Further you can ask. 
EDIT : For particle generation you can use this code

```
public void generateParticles(float pX, float pY) {

    pointParticleEmtitter = new PointParticleEmitter(pX, pY);

    particleSystem = new ParticleSystem(pointParticleEmtitter, maxRate,
            minRate, maxParticles, mParticleTextureRegion.deepCopy());

    particleSystem.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE);
    particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new ColorInitializer(0.8f, 0.43f,
            0.2f));
    particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new AlphaModifier(1, 0, 0, 0.25f));
    particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new ExpireModifier(0.25f));

    gameObject.getScene().attachChild(particleSystem);

}
```

For Line algorithm you can use this one

```
public void drawLine() {
    int x;
    float y, m;

    x = (int) previousX;
    y = (int) previousY;

    m = (currentY - previousY) / (currentX - previousX);

    if (Math.round(previousX) == Math.round(currentX)) {
        if (previousY < currentY) {
            for (y = (int) previousY; y < currentY; ++y)
                pointParticleEmtitter.setCenter(previousX, y);
        } else {
            for (y = (int) previousY; y > currentY; --y)
                pointParticleEmtitter.setCenter(previousX, y);
        }
    } else {
        if (previousX < currentX) {
            for (x = (int) previousX; x < currentX; ++x) {
                y = m * (x - previousX) + previousY;
                pointParticleEmtitter.setCenter(x, y);
            }
        } else if (previousX > currentX) {
            for (x = (int) previousX; x > currentX; --x) {
                y = m * (x - currentX) + currentY;
                pointParticleEmtitter.setCenter(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give me any java code example?? or Andengine example?

Comment: thanks a lot....but a lil more guidance plz.
Suppose I have an array with x,y points in it. How will I call the above algo and how particle system functions is connected to line algorithms? I mean where it is called?

Comment: You have to supply each pair of (x,y) coordinate to the function and this thing you have to manage in onManageUpdate() method. First you have to create particle using generateParticles() method that you have to call single time and in update method you have to call drawLine method by providing appropriate x,y coordinate.

Comment: ok thanks a lot m trying it... I will bother you again if there will be any problems

Comment: If you find your answer then you have to mark as correct for providing encouragement and guidance to community members

Comment: I didnt get the desired results....... :( Not even close to what I was looking for.