# Android (AndEngine): Drawing with touch using particles

Tags: android, opengl-es, drawing, andengine, particles

In my app I'm implementing a draw feature involving particles... basically it needs to work pretty much like Art of Glow (this app here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIZpw1VslIk).

What I do is this: I create the particle system and the emitter (the Point type); on every touch event I move the emitter in the position pressed so that it looks like that the particles are following the finger...

If I'm drawing slowly it works great, but if I move faster doing for example a straight line, the line will be frammented.

I tried then doing a recusrive function that basically from the previous point to the next set the position of the emitter in the middle point between them and does the same for the middle parts that go from the previous point to the middle part and from the middle part to the next (I don't know if you'll understand what I did... don't know how to explain it in english  ), but still the line will be frammented.

So I'm thinking that the app, when you move fast, "has no time" to move the emitter in every point and that's why a straight line will be frammented... So, do you have any ideas on how to make it as efficient as Art of Glow? That app looses only few inputs and I don't understand how the author made it like that...

Answer (score 1):

When you obtain the touch inputs, are you using the current position only? It looks like you tried making a tweener(something to generate the in-between frames), but Android can provide you with more inputs for fast movement. Check out [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html), especially the "Batching" section.

Basically, you can use `geHistoricalX/Y` and `getHistoricalEventTime` to fill in your missing points. If that doesn't get it perfect, doing that in combination with your current method should get you as close as possible.

Comment: Thanks for anwsering! Yes I'm doing that too (sorry, I forgot to say that!) but it doesn't change a bit. Like I said it's probably because it can't move the emitter that fast... So yesterday I tried another thing; I made 2 other particle systems, connected to 2 other emitter; what I did was cycle them when I obtain the touch input, so that at the moment X the first one is moved; at the moment Y the second one, at the moment Z the third one, and so on repeating; this way every emitter has the time to actually show itself in the scene

Comment: Doing that works... well sort of, because it still looses some inputs...For now it's better than nothing, but there's probably a better way I don't know yet...

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21724810/472336

Check this ... This works correctly for mos t scenarios still needed improvements